# Raw cast of arbitrary string to integer

Tags: varchar, cast

I have non-numeric string IDs in a table, and would like to cast them to unique integers. I need the mapping to be invertible / one-to-one. The string IDs are of uniform length.

I want to do this by literally aggregating the ASCII codes of each character in the ID. The `ASCII` function only returns the leftmost character. Is there an efficient way to cast the entire string?

Comment: Why?  How long is the string?   Even if the string is ASCII then integer is only 4 characters.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using SQL Server, which you still haven't confirmed, I'd use an inline table-valued-function (TVF) that can be used to efficiently and safely convert character-data into an integer value, for strings of 8 characters or less.  The string must be a maximum of 8 characters in length since that is the maximum number of bytes for an integer in SQL Server.

This is the TVF:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetBigInt') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetBigInt;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetBigInt (@data VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
SELECT BigIntResult = CASE WHEN LEN(@data) > 8 THEN 1/0 
    ELSE CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @data, 0)) END;
GO
```

To test the function, I created the following test-bed table with some sample rows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t;
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    SomeText VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #t (SomeText)
VALUES ('aaaaaaaa')
    , ('AAAAAAAA')
    , ('aaaaaaab')
    , ('ZZZZZZZZ')
    , ('ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ')
    , (CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1) + CHAR(1))
    , (CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(127))
    , (CHAR(128) + CHAR(127) + CHAR(128) + CHAR(128) + CHAR(128) + CHAR(128) + CHAR(128) + CHAR(128))
    , ('aaaaaaaba');
```

Run the TVF against the table like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM #t t
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetBigInt(t.SomeText) g;
```

The last row in the sample intentionally has 9 characters, which cannot be reliably converted into an 8-byte integer.  When the TVF attempts to convert that row, it will display the following error:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

The results for the other rows in the sample data are:

[image]

To test the speed of the TVF, I inserted 1,000,000 rows into the table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO #t (SomeText)
SELECT TOP(1000000) LEFT(c1.name, 8)
FROM sys.columns c1
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns c3;
```

The execution plan for the query running against 1,000,000 rows:

[image]

If your "non-numeric string IDs" are longer than 8 bytes, I'd recommend simply converting them to `BINARY(x)` or `VARBINARY(x)` values, where `x` is then maximum length of your character data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetBinary') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetBinary;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetBinary (@data VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
SELECT BinaryResult = CONVERT(VARBINARY(1000), @data, 0);
GO

SELECT *
FROM #t t
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetBinary(t.SomeText) g;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be integer? Otherwise hex(s) might do the trick. Example:

```
values hex('a12babab')"

1               
----------------
6131326261626162
```

If you need a bijection from String -> Int, the String can't be very long

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by others, by casting to integer, you are limited to the number of characters you can encode/decode.  This 'appears' to work on my limited test cases.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max) = 'abcd'
DECLARE @Int INT

--Convert from varchar to int
SET @Int = Convert(INT, convert(VARBINARY(max), @str))
SELECT @int

--Convert from int to varchar
SET @str = Convert(VARCHAR(max), convert(VARBINARY(max), @int))
SELECT @str
GO
```